# combine two arraylist in one with certain order or a serial id

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, hashmap

I couldn't find a better title than that so pardon me for any kind of confusion.

I want to combine two hashmap into one hashmap.I am actually using hashmaps to contain the datas of table where `key=coloumName` and `value= coloumValues`.
My code looks something like

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList> FTMap = table1.getColumn().getColumnValues()
HashMap<String, ArrayList> STMap = table2.getColumn().getColumnValues()

HashMap<String, ArrayList> FinalTableMap = new HashMap()

FinalTableMap.putAll(FTMap)
FinalTableMap.putAll(STMap)
```

I don't have any problem with column names but the order of coloumvalues are not working after the combining. Since i am using arraylist,i am trying to compare two arraylist and put it in a final arraylist which can be used as the value of the final hashmap.I need some advice or suggestion for this matching between two arraylist.

Comment: My code contains some other things(which is working) So I didnt submit any codes here.If my question was not clear enough please let me know.

Comment: some examples of hashmap content and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: yankee -lets assume the contents of hashmap is like

Comment: FTMap- 
Name id Gender
A    1   Male
B    2   Female
C    3   Male

STMap

Name Gender Country
X    Male   Australia
A    Male   Germany
B    Female India

my output is like

Name id Gender  Country
A    1   Male   Australia
B    2  Female Germany
C    3    Male   India 
X         Male

what i want is

Name Id Gender Country
A    1   Male   Germany
B    2  Female India
C    3    Male   Null 
X    null Male   Australia @yankee thanks

Comment: @user1464906 Unreadable. Please edit that into your post where you can format it properly.

Comment: What does 'the order of column values not working' mean?

Answer (score 1):

After you have used `addAll` to combine your lists, you can use [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort your `ArrayList`. In your `Comparator`'s [compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) function, you will compare the two objects using the values you wish to sort by (you mentioned serial id?).

See [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) for a brief example.